# How can I delete item from nested array using arrayRemove?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone tell me why this does not work:

```
const deleteItem = index => {
   firebase
     .firestore()
     .collection("user")
     .doc(user1)
     .update({
       Travellers : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({Name: item.Travellers[index].Name, Weight: item.Travellers[index].Weight})
     })
  };
```

The array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "rWFZhAKk9eOSIIFoP0DqqvrC6WJ3",
        "Travellers": [
            {
                "Name": "Mike",
                "Weight": "100.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Bob",
                "Weight": "95.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The code works fine for arrayUnion when adding to this array, but removing it is not. If I hardcode the values into Name and Weight then it removes just fine.

Console returns (before the firebase.update) Mike and 100.00 as index 0.

Firebase screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from Firebase]

Comment: "If I hardcode the values into Name and Weight then it removes just fine." That seems key to your answer. If hardcoding the values works, the code to remove the item is fine and the problem is that your `item.Travellers[index].Name` are not the same as the hard-coded values. Running the code in a debugger is probably the fastest way to determine why that is.

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best it'll get closed, but it may get you banned from the site. Instead, update your original post with the additional information you added here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen they match up - console.log({Name: item.Travellers[index].Name, Weight: item.Travellers[index].Weight}); returns {
"Name": "Mike", "Weight": "100.00" } but it still refuses to remove it

Comment: I found related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276269/how-to-delete-the-array-elements-at-index-in-firestore-in-javascript) in it is explained that you cannot remove by index, because it only works with the complete value of the array.