# Update field inside an array in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the booked field (best would be toogle). The booked field is inside a map wich itself is inside an array.
I have the index of the map, i just dont get how to navigate to the "booked" field.
I can also read the doc etc. no problem there.

[image]

If relevant the code is in react

I really tried a lot of different ways.
How hard can it be to update a field in a db.
So i thought anyways.

every help is highly appreciated

Comment: In short - read the document, modify the array in memory, update the document with the new array.  There is no other way.

Comment: If you can, change the array into a map. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276269/how-to-delete-the-array-elements-at-index-in-firestore-in-javascript/62278041#62278041

Comment: @l1b3rty Thanks, i will change to nested maps